# intent.getStringExtra

Tags: android

Estoy intentando traerme unas cosillas desde un `recyclerview` y el caso es que si puedo el nombre pero ni la categoría ni la imagen. ¿Como lo puedo conseguir?

```
public class Platos_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Platos_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    List<Estadisticas> estadisticas;

    public Platos_Adapter(List<Estadisticas> estadisticas, Context context) {
        super();
        this.estadisticas = estadisticas;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.platos_row, parent, false );
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.root.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Toast.makeText(context, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                        //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Toast.makeText(context, estadisticas.get(position).getEquipo_Local(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





                Intent intent= new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("Nombre", estadisticas.get(position).getEquipo_Local());
                intent.putExtra("Categoria", estadisticas.get(position).getEquipo_Visitante());
                intent.putExtra("Imagen", estadisticas.get(position).getEscudo_Local());

                context.startActivity(intent);

                //.getText().toString());

                Estadisticas estadisticas1 = estadisticas.get( getAdapterPosition() );
            }

            private int getAdapterPosition() {
                return 0;
            }
        } );
        Estadisticas superHero = estadisticas.get( position );
        imageLoader = DecoracionLineaDivisoria.CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance( context ).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get( superHero.getEscudo_Local(), ImageLoader.getImageListener( holder.escudo_local, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert ) );
        holder.escudo_local.setImageUrl( superHero.getEscudo_Local(), imageLoader );
        holder.textViewEquipo_Local.setText( superHero.getEquipo_Local() );
        holder.textViewCategoria.setText( superHero.getEquipo_Visitante() );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return estadisticas.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView escudo_local;
        public TextView textViewEquipo_Local;
        public TextView textViewCategoria;
        public View root;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super( itemView );
            root = itemView;
            escudo_local = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.tv_esc_local );
            textViewEquipo_Local = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.tv_ek_local );
            textViewCategoria = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.tv_ek_visi );
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity.class**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView categoria;
    private ImageView imageView;


    //public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "Nombre";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Intent intent = getIntent();


        categoria = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

        String Name = intent.getStringExtra("Nombre");

        TextView categoria = intent.getStringExtra("Categoria");


        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(Name);
        loadBackdrop();
    }

    private void loadBackdrop() {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        Glide.with(this).load(imageView).centerCrop().into(imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_detail.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_info_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ddddddddddddddd" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_categoria"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="aaaa" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Related"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ddddddddddd" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Este es el error

```
Error:(36, 51) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TextView
```

Gracias

Comment: Rafa estas realizando correctamente el envio de datos pero solo tienes un error al realizar casting de uno de esos valores como tipo TextView lo cual es incorrecto.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> Error:(36, 51) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted
>   to TextView

El envió y recibido de los valores mediante un `bundle` es correcto, el problema es aquí:

```
  TextView categoria = intent.getStringExtra("Categoria");
```

Debes recibir un tipo String:

```
  String Categoria = intent.getStringExtra("Categoria");
```

este valor después lo puedes usar para agregarlo a tu `TextView` `categoria`:

```
categoria.setText(Categoria);
```

Comment: Cambiando TextView por String me cierra la aplicacion sin mostrar ningun error

Comment: Revisa el LogCat que otro detalle muestra?

Comment: la plicacion se abre, cuando se cierra es cuando pulso sobre la imagen para abrir la activity de detalles y es a causa de glide ya que desactivandolo si me habre bien, pero no muestra la categoria.

Comment: Agrega lo que marca el LogCat, de otra forma hay muchas causas para que se cierre la applicacion

Comment: at com.ramon.capascual.DetailActivity.loadBackdrop(DetailActivity.java:47)
                                                                         at com.ramon.capascual.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:42)

Comment: Que hay en (DetailActivity.j‌​ava linea 42

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51198/discussion-between-elenasys-and-rafel-c-f).

Comment: en la linea 42 no hay nada
en la 47 un cierre de llave }
*Linea 41      } 

private void loadBackdrop() { 
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop); 
//Glide.with(this).load(imageView).centerCrop().into(imageView); 
Linea 47     }